# Make localstorage dataset created with a local webapp in Firefox accessible to the same webapp when run in Chrome or other browsers

Tags: cross-browser, local-storage

I wrote a webapp that I use to store various information locally using Local Storage in Firefox.  I want to run the webapp in Chrome or another brower using the same local storage data.  Is that possible?  If not, is it possible to copy the local storage data created by the webapp in Firefox to a file that can be used by the same webapp in Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localStorage is a storage on client side(web browser), you can't share localStorage of one browser with other.

Although you can copy localStorage content by running given javascript in browser console

```
copy(JSON.stringify(localStorage));
```

it'll copy all localStorage content to clipboard.
Now, you can import it into another browser by running given javascript in console

```
var data = '/*paste stringified JSON from clipboard*/'; 
 Object.keys(data).forEach(function (k)   { 
  localStorage.setItem(k, data[k]); 
 });
```

Comment: The first part of the code worked nicely in the Firefox console.  When I pasted the clipboard contents into the Chrome console inside the parens of the second code and entered it, I go the following error.            Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:17------Any ideas?

Comment: you need to escape double quotes in string, add \ before each double quote.

Comment: From a cursory search, it looks like I'm trying to parse a string that's already been parsed so maybe wondering if data should be just set to equal the string instead of including the JSON.parse command in the second string.  Working on it now but not great with JSON so any ideas would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: So use the replace command to escape every instance of " in the entire string, is that correct?

Comment: no, escape and replace are different things, try this while copying, it may escape it for you copy(JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(localStorage)));

Comment: I went ahead and removed the JSON.parse('string') command from the second script and just set the data equal to the clipboard string and it worked.  I'll try your solution and if it works also, I'll give credit accordingly though not sure how to allocate it when answer is comprised with multiple inputs/corrections.

Comment: I tried the modified copy command which escaped every instance of " with a backslash and tried it with and without the JSON.parse command in the second half of your original code but neither method worked.  So the answer that worked is using your original code after removing the JSON.parse command from the second half.  In other words, just setting data equal to the clipboard contents generated by the first half of the code.  So how do I give you credit for the part of your code that worked?

Comment: Do I write a new answer or do you amend your code or ?  I'll give you all the points if allowed but not sure how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, that was great.  Saved me alot of headaches.  Been trying to migrate to Chrome after Firefox murdered the one NPAPI plugin I had to have to run my webapp and this gets me down the road alot.